# rh-postgresql96(Red Hat provided postgresql) vs postgresql-9.6 (community postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, postgresql-9.6, repmgr

Our client has provided us Red Hat machine for setting up PostgreSQL. We are allowed to install red hat provided packages only.

So we have to install red hat provided postgresql (rh-postgresql96) instead of postgresql-9.6.

Is it a good approach to go with red hat specific PostgreSQL in production instead of community PostgreSQL?

Also, we are trying to set up repmgr for this PostgreSQL in the local environment but we didn't find any suitable package for this PostgreSQL.

How can we install any high availability solution like repmgr for Red Hat provided PostgreSQL?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at: [enterprisedb](https://www.enterprisedb.com)?

Comment: enterprisedb is not listed in Red hat provided packages.

Comment: Does the RH package get the regular PostgreSQL updates?  Also, does it have all the necessary extensions and other bits (apps)?

Comment: it does have all necessary extensions but I am not sure about compatibility with other open source tools present for community PostgreSQL.

Comment: I would think it is compatible with other open source tools.  Redhat is just packaging the software, not forking it entirely.  But it doesn't matter if those tools are compatible, if your client won't let you use them.

Comment: @Python I'm also in-search of HA solution for Red Hat provided PostgreSQL9.6, Have you got any HA solutions?

Comment: First, we created a solution including some manual scripts and crons to check service downtime. But it was not covering all scenarios. Now we are testing HA with patrony and it is working fine as of now.